# How do you stub a `current_user` with update_attributes set to false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

This is a pure syntactical question. I'm very new to RSpec.

I basically want to write something on the lines of this erroring line :

```
controller.stub!(:current_user(:update_attributes => false))
```

Anyone know how to properly write that?

RSpec's default looks like this :

```
User.stub(:find) { mock_user(:update_attributes => false) }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a case for `stub_chain`:

`controller.stub_chain(:current_user,:update_attributes).and_return(false)`

Note that this is just going to replace methods in the list in the order they occur, so for this to make sense you'll have a `current_user.update_attributes` in your controller. If you have something like `@user.update_attributes`, I don't think it will work.

More info on [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Mocks/Methods/stub_chain)

Comment: Yours works too! Stub_chaining is amazing! :D Where would I be without Zetetic? Probably working at a McDonalds

Answer (score 6):

I just blindly played around with a thousand variations and finally got it to pass with this :

```
controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@user)
@user.stub!(:update_attributes => false)
```

But seriously, does that even make any sense? It's passing :D

Comment: Makes perfect sense. current_user is a method which returns an instance of User. current_user does not have an update_attributes method, User does. So stubbing update_attributes for current_user doesn't do anything but stubbing it for the instance of User works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

With RSpec 3.0 and [rspec-mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) the way to do this is to use `allow`.

```
before(:each) do
  @user = mock_model(User)
  allow(controller).to(receive(:current_user).and_return(@user))
  allow(@user).to(receive(:update_attributes).and_return(false))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not address update_attributes specifically, but the following worked for me. Assuming your current_user helper lives in ApplicationController:

```
user = double(:user)
allow(controller).to(receive(:current_user).and_return(user))
allow(controller.current_user).to receive(:is_admin?).and_return(false)

current_user.is_admin? # => false
```